# Split date range equally

Tags: php

I'm trying to split a date range in equal parts

i try :

```
    function splitDates($min, $max, $parts = 7, $output = "Y-m-d") {
        $dataCollection = array();
        $diff = (strtotime($max) - strtotime($min)) / $parts;
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $parts; $i++) {
            $convert = $i == 1 ? $min : end($dataCollection);
            $dataCollection[] = $i !== $parts ? date($output, strtotime($convert) + $diff) : date($output, strtotime($max));
        }

        return $dataCollection;
    }

    $min = "2014-01-01";
    $max = "2016-01-01";
    $dates = splitDates($min, $max);

    echo "<pre>";
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($dates as $value) {
        $i++;
        echo "data $i  : $value <br>";
    }
    echo "</pre>";
```

output :

```
date 1  : 2014-04-15 
date 2  : 2014-07-28 
date 3  : 2014-11-09 
date 4  : 2015-02-21 
date 5  : 2015-06-05 
date 6  : 2015-09-17 
date 7  : 2016-01-01
```

the result is not as expected, the first date is always the $min and the last is always the $max

the interval between the dates are not accurate

Comment: What are the dates you expect?

Comment: The dates are split at 104 days.

Comment: hello John, well in my example the difference is 2 years so (365 × 2) ÷ 7 = 104,285714286 days
104,285714286 ÷ 31 = 3,36 month difference
I want the closest possible result so calculated the difference between seconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a little simplified your code and it began to work

```
 function splitDates($min, $max, $parts = 7, $output = "Y-m-d") {
        $dataCollection[] = date($output, strtotime($min));
        $diff = (strtotime($max) - strtotime($min)) / $parts;
        $convert = strtotime($min) + $diff;

        for ($i = 1; $i < $parts; $i++) {
            $dataCollection[] = date($output, $convert);
            $convert += $diff;
        }
        $dataCollection[] = date($output, strtotime($max));
        return $dataCollection;
    }
```